# ciscoconfparse BGP no description on one of the neighbor

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ciscoconfparse

i am trying to use ciscoconfparse to extract neighbor, remote as, and description into the dictionary. however one of the neighbor does not have description. hence it will not return the value

can anyone help what it would be the correct way to also get all neighbor values

```
Config:
router bgp 42098001
 neighbor SERVER peer-group
 neighbor SERVER remote-as 64700
 neighbor 10.29.0.65 remote-as 1111
 neighbor 10.29.0.65 description to ZZZ
 neighbor 10.29.0.73 remote-as 2222
 neighbor 10.29.0.73 description to AAA
 neighbor 10.29.0.81 remote-as 3333
 neighbor 10.29.0.81 description to BBB
 neighbor 10.29.0.90 remote-as 4209800190
 neighbor 10.29.0.90 description to ABC 
 neighbor 10.232.122.170 remote-as 64700
 neighbor 10.232.122.170 description ABD
 neighbor 10.237.34.2 remote-as 4209800192
 neighbor 10.237.34.2 description to CCC
```

```
    bgp_as_name = confparse.find_all_children(r"^router bgp")

    for details in bgp_as_name:
        if 'remote-as' in details:
            remote_ip = details.strip().rsplit(' ')[1]
            as_number = details.strip().rsplit(' ')[3]
            #print(remote_ip)

        if 'description' in details:
            description = details.strip().rsplit(' ')[3:]
            desc = (' ').join(description)
            bgp_as_ip.update({'description': desc})
            print(bgp_as_ip)


    #BGP route-map
    bgp_route_map = confparse.find_all_children(r"^router bgp")
    for routemap in bgp_route_map:
        if 'route-map' in routemap:
            bgp_routemap_slice1 = routemap.strip().split(' ')[0:2]
            bgp_routemap_slice2 = routemap.strip().split(' ')[-2:]
            bgp_routemap_combine = bgp_routemap_slice1 + bgp_routemap_slice2
            bgp_route_map = bgp_routemap_combine[1:4]
            print(bgp_route_map)
            #bgp_as_ip.update({'route-map': bgp_route_map})
            #print(bgp_as_ip)
```

```
RESULT
{'remote_ip': '10.29.0.65', 'as_num': '1111', 'description': 'to ZZZ'}
{'remote_ip': '10.29.0.73', 'as_num': '2222', 'description': 'to AAA'}
{'remote_ip': '10.29.0.81', 'as_num': '3333', 'description': 'to BBB'}
{'remote_ip': '10.29.0.90', 'as_num': '4201', 'description': 'to ABC'}
{'remote_ip': '10.232.122.170', 'as_num': '64700', 'description': 'ABD'}
{'remote_ip': '10.237.34.2', 'as_num': '4209', 'description': 'to CCC'}
```

**> The missing information is neighbor SERVER**

Comment: SERVER is not a "real" neighbor; it is a peer-group. Furthermore, even for real neighbors, a description is not mandatory, so you should be handle the case of neighbors without a description.

Comment: Thanks for reply. my intention is to get neighbor information ( peer/remote, as, description) and put it to excel file. i am missing the neighbor information that does not have description in the configuration. i am trying to put "none" if there is no description but turn out the rest of bgp config (like password, route-map) also getting "none" value.

Comment: are you still having this problem?  If not, go ahead and post your solution so they question doesn't appear unanswered

Answer (score 1):

ciscoconfparse has a method called [`re_match_typed()`](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_IOSCfgLine.html?highlight=re_match_typed#ciscoconfparse.models_cisco.IOSCfgLine.re_match_typed) for pretty much this exact case...

```py
from pprint import pprint

from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

config_list = """router bgp 42098001
 neighbor SERVER peer-group
 neighbor SERVER remote-as 64700
 neighbor 10.29.0.65 remote-as 1111
 neighbor 10.29.0.65 description to ZZZ
 neighbor 10.29.0.73 remote-as 2222
 neighbor 10.29.0.73 description to AAA
 neighbor 10.29.0.81 remote-as 3333
 neighbor 10.29.0.81 description to BBB
 neighbor 10.29.0.90 remote-as 4209800190
 neighbor 10.29.0.90 description to ABC
 neighbor 10.232.122.170 remote-as 64700
 neighbor 10.232.122.170 description ABD
 neighbor 10.237.34.2 remote-as 4209800192
 neighbor 10.237.34.2 description to CCC
""".splitlines()

parse = CiscoConfParse(config_list)


nested_dict = dict()
for obj_cmd in parse.find_objects(r"^\s+neighbor"):
    nei_ipv4 = obj_cmd.re_match_typed(r"^\s+neighbor\s+(\S+)", result_type=str)

    nei_new_addr = nested_dict.get(nei_ipv4, False)
    if nei_new_addr is False:
        nested_dict[nei_ipv4] = dict()

    if nested_dict[nei_ipv4].get("remote-as", None) is None:
        nested_dict[nei_ipv4]["remote-as"] = obj_cmd.re_match_typed(
            r"^\s*neighbor\s+{0}\s+remote-as\s+(\d+)\s*$".format(nei_ipv4),
            untyped_default=True,
            default=None,
        )

    if nested_dict[nei_ipv4].get("description", None) is None:
        nested_dict[nei_ipv4]["description"] = obj_cmd.re_match_typed(
            r"^\s*neighbor\s+{0}\s+description\s+(\S.*)\s*$".format(nei_ipv4),
            untyped_default=True,
            default=None,
        )

pprint(nested_dict)
```

Running this, the output is...

```
{'10.232.122.170': {'description': 'ABD', 'remote-as': '64700'},
 '10.237.34.2': {'description': 'to CCC', 'remote-as': '4209800192'},
 '10.29.0.65': {'description': 'to ZZZ', 'remote-as': '1111'},
 '10.29.0.73': {'description': 'to AAA', 'remote-as': '2222'},
 '10.29.0.81': {'description': 'to BBB', 'remote-as': '3333'},
 '10.29.0.90': {'description': 'to ABC ', 'remote-as': '4209800190'},
 'SERVER': {'description': None, 'remote-as': '64700'}}
```

I reformatted the output, but it's trivial to change the example to use your format...